# Смысл записи "input[type="checkbox"] + label"

Tags: css

Кто может разъяснить такую запись, а именно: "input[type="checkbox"] + label"

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    background: url(sprite.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Применяет стили к чекбоксу
2. Применяет стили к label, который идёт сразу после чекбокса
3. Применяет стили к label, который идёт сразу после выбранного чекбокса

[Селекторы CSS](http://everstudent.ru/blog/htmlcss/30-css-seletors-to-memorize/)

Comment: спасибо, отличная шпаргалка

Answer (score 0):

Стилизует чекбокс - заменяет стандарт на красивый дизайнерский.